# Create an entity which expire in NodeJS with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, web

I want to create an entity(an ad) which expire in one month. How can I do this in NodeJS with MongoDB?
The perfect example would be instagram/facebook stories, which expires after a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `expiration` attribute and set it to one day in the future. You could use a package like `moment` to do this.

Then, if a user attempts to retrieve an expired post, just respond with a 404 status code.

If you want to clean it up, use a `cron` task to clean up expired ads.

```
let ad = {...ad, expiration: moment().add(1, "days").valueOf()}
```

moment: https://momentjs.com/

cron: https://crontab.guru/

cron would ideally run a script or a fetch request to an endpoint that would delete expired entries.

There is no way to just tell Mongo to delete a document after 1 day.

Comment: it worked, but how can I get an error from the cron job if I have one?

Comment: @MariusAtesiei You will find those in your server's error logs. Use a process manager like `pm2` https://pm2.keymetrics.io/ Make sure you use a try/catch block if you're expecting errors and use `console.error()` to log the error. Then use a separate file for your errors. https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/ You can use a plaintext file called `errors`.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo has TTL (time to live fields) - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/ - you can set a document to disappear after a certain time.